# Solidworks Motion capabilities

Tags: automotive-engineering, simulation, solidworks

Is Solidworks Motion capable of finding the torque of the planet carrier (output) in a planetary gear set when in steady state? The sun and ring gears are both inputs and all gears are rotating at a constant angular velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, if you define all physical properties (mass, moment of inertia ...) of the rotating object. You need to run the simulation first, notice put the motor at the component which you want to find the torque of.

1- Click on results.

2- Under property manger (under results) select 'forces'.

3- Select 'motor torque' under subcategory.

4- Select 'magnitude' of whatever component you are interested in.

5 click on the green check mark.

You'll see the plot in function of time. 
This is also true for finding power, forces, acceleration ... .